# why does crontab - returns 0481-071 error on aix

Tags: cron, aix

On Linux I use

```
cat filename | ssh dradmqa1@10.196.33.12 "crontab -" ..
```

to replace a remote crontab.
If I execute this on AIX I get : crontab: 0481-071 Cannot access the  file
I can execute

```
ssh dradmqa1@10.196.33.12 "crontab -l"
```

and receive correct output,
but replacing the crontab is not working.
Is there a special option/setting to be done for AIX?

Comment: I'm guessing `crontab` on AIX simply does not accept `-` to mean to read standard input. Can you remove the `ssh` fluff and experiment locally on the AIX box to establish what exactly the problem is? (Also probably have someone take a look at your keyboard.)

Comment: thks for the update. yes the crontab - option does not exist on aix. I changed the script and for aix : I scp the file to the target aix and execute ssh xx    crontab filename.  this is working. best regards, Guiy

Answer (score 1):

AIX crontab haven't got such option, also your method would overwrite crontab without creating a backup. Try something like this:

```
cat newcrontabfile | ssh aixuser@aixhost '
 umask 077;
 Now=$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S);
 crontab -l >crontab.before.$Now;
 cat >crontab.after.$Now;
 crontab crontab.after.$Now'
```

Edit: added `umask 077` -- you might not want others to see your crontab files

Comment: The predictable temporary file name is a potential security problem; perhaps see if AIX offers something like `mktemp` for creating secure temporary files.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for pointing this out; AIX has got `mktemp(1)` so something like `NewFile=$(/usr/bin/mktemp)`  can be used.

Comment: With `mktemp` you should not separately need the `umask` either.

Comment: (Off: I would suggest keeping the files, for later investigations: _when did someone stop the most important daily backup?)_